# How to authenticate with login and password using OAuth2?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a service with no UI that must connect to a web API using OAuth2. I have everything - Client ID, Client Secret, Auth URL, Callback URL, Username, and Password.

I want to know the easiest way to exchange the username, password, etc. for an OAuth2 token so I may authenticate with the web API.

I've been looking at [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org/), and the canonical workflow seems to be:

1. Use `OAuthClientRequest` to build the request URI
2. Redirect to the URI so the user can grant access
3. Retrieve the corresponding code via `OAuthAccessTokenResponse` and use it to authenticate

Again - I cannot have the app prompt the user; everything must happen programmatically.

I think I'm looking for something like `DotNetOpenAuth`'s `ExchangeUserCredentialForToken()` method, but for Java.

I'm leaning towards using [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org/), but I'm open to any framework / solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the authentication methods implemented by the Authorization Server (the entity that will give you `access_tokens`).

At the protocol level, you are looking for the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.3

Not all Authorization Servers implement this though so you will need to check their docs. (e.g Facebook, Twitter, Google don't provide this, as an example).

It's a really simple interaction, so generally, you won't need a (client) framework for this. Here's a sample of what the HTTP request looks like: https://auth0.com/docs/flows/resource-owner-password-flow

Comment: I must add that the REST 2.0 client libraries are just awesome for implementing OAuth clients, I really recommend that instead of Apache Oltu.

Comment: These links are out of date. Any chance they could be updated?